# Best practice SQL log

Tags: sql, join, logging

I have an application which handles users, itemcreations, edits and deletes.

What is the best approach to log stuff? The LogTable will grow big very fast since I log every time an item is edited or deleted.

I have 2 solutions:

## 1

In this solution I will log creations of items in their respective table BUT all other actions in a seperate LogTable. Pro is that I dont have to join to get info.

ItemTable: ID, ItemSerialNumber, ItemCreatedBy, ItemCreatedTime

LogTable: ID, Action, ItemRefID, UserID, Time

## 2

In this solution I will log everything in LogTable (this requires joins when I get info about each item)

ItemTable: ID, ItemSerialNumber

LogTable: ID, Action, ItemRefID, UserID, Time

Comment: https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/database-administration/pop-rivetts-sql-server-faq-no.5-pop-on-the-audit-trail/

Comment: @CodingDefined Thanks for the comment, but I have already looked into Triggers. The problem is that they are based around users in the Database. But I have one single SQL-user which the application uses to access the Database.

Comment: so when there is a single user all the activities of that particular user will be recorded, now you can customize accordingly.

Comment: @CodingDefined But how will I be able to distinguish the different users in my application? The only way I see that is if I create more tables to log that. And then triggers doesnt make sence anymore. Or is there something Im missing?

Comment: why cant you send a username as well, when you are recording the activity of the user or say user id, that makes sense to me to distinguish two user

Comment: @CodingDefined I will take a look at it. Maybe I dropped the idea too fast. Thanks!